# C - how do you access value from a pointer to a pointer to that value?

Tags: c, pointers

This function needs to be passed a pointer to a pointer.

```
void get_name(person** p) {
    puts(p->name); // this is probably wrong
}
```

This is how I call the function (I'm not sure about this either):

```
int main() {
    ...

    get_name(&person); // is this wrong?

    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Person is obviously a struct with a name property which is a string.

How do you refer to the value *p points to from **p?

Comment: The proper return type of `main` is `int`, not `void`.

Comment: I know that, but here I wanted to spare the "return 0;" at the end, I changed it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`x->y` is just a shortcut for `(*x).y`.  `*` performs indirection (that is, it gives you the thing pointed to by the pointer), so you need to perform indirection twice to get the thing pointed to the pointer that is pointed to by the pointer:

```
(**p).name
(*p)->name
```

If `person` is the name of a typedefed struct, then `get_name(&person)` is not correct; you need an instance of that struct and you need a pointer to that instance that you can pass to the function:

```
int main() {
    person p;
    person* pp = &p;
    get_name(&pp);
}
```

However, it's not exactly clear why `get_name` needs to take a `person**`; presumably a `person*` would be sufficient.